# Aligning buttons in toolbar using flex

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

I am new in react native and I really get stuck in aligning a two toolbar buttons for two days! I need to put them in the right part of my tool bar using flex. However, I couldn't do that. Here is the code:

```
export default class ToolbarHorizontal extends Component {

  // component prop types
  static propTypes = {
    items: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.shape({
      active: React.PropTypes.bool,
      name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      imageSourceActive: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      imageSourceInactive: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      onOpen: PropTypes.func,
    })).isRequired,
    toolbarActiveItem: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    forcedPath: React.PropTypes.bool,
    forcedPathImageSource: React.PropTypes.number,
    tintColor: React.PropTypes.string,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.toolbarActiveIndex = props.items.map((el) => el.name).indexOf(props.toolbarActiveItem);
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    let { toolbarActiveItem } = this.props;
    let { forcedPath } = this.props;
    let { forcedPathImageSource } = this.props;
    let { tintColor } = this.props;
    tintColor = (tintColor) ? tintColor : '#000'; // default value is black
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} >
        <ScrollView
          horizontal={true}
          collapsable={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          style={styles.scroller}
        >
   <View style={styles.componentContainer}>
        { items.map((item, index) => {
            let active = (item.active !== undefined) ? item.active : true; // default value is true
            if (active) {
              return(
                <View key={item.id} style={styles.imageContianer}>
                  {(toolbarActiveItem == item.name) &&
                    <View style={styles.insideImageContainer}>
                      <Image
                        source={item.imageSourceSection}
                        style={styles.item}
                      />
                      <Text size={20} style={{color:tintColor, paddingRight:10}}>{!forcedPath ? item.description : null}</Text>
                    </View>
                  }
                </View>
              );
            }
          }
        )}


<View style={styles.buttomContainer}>
        { items.map((item, index) => {
            //console.log('toolbarActiveItem == item.name:', toolbarActiveItem, '==', item.name);
            let active = (item.active !== undefined) ? item.active : true; // default value is true
            if (active && (!forcedPath || item.isVisibleWhenForcedPath)) {
              return(
                <View key={item.id} >
                  {item.isTouchable && forcedPath && index > 0 &&
                    <Image
                      source={forcedPathImageSource}
                      style={styles.forcedPathImage}
                    />
                  }
                  {item.isTouchable &&
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                      if (!forcedPath) { // when forcedPath, buttons are never touchable
                        if (toolbarActiveItem != item.name) {
                          item.onOpen(item.name);
                          toolbarActiveItem = item.name;
                        }
                        else
                        { // already on opened page, go back if button is pressed again
                          this.props.navigation.goBack();
                        }
                      }
                    }}>
                      {forcedPath &&
                        <Image
                          source={(toolbarActiveItem == item.name) ? item.imageSourceForcedPathActive : index > this.toolbarActiveIndex ? item.imageSourceForcedPathTobevisited : item.imageSourceForcedPathVisited}
                          style={styles.item}
                        />
                      }
                      {!forcedPath &&
                        <Image
                          source={(toolbarActiveItem == item.name) ? item.imageSourceActive : item.imageSourceInactive}
                          style={styles.item}
                        />
                      }
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  }
                </View>
              );
            }
          }
        )}
          </View>
        </View>

        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:0.16,
    flexDirection:'row' ,

    //backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  componentContainer: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection:'row',
    alignContent:'center',
    alignItems: 'center',

  },
  imageContianer: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection:'row',
    alignContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',

  },
  buttomContainer: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection:'row',
  //  backgroundColor: '#9b59b6' ,
  },
insideImageContainer: {
  flex:1,
  alignItems:'center',
  flexDirection:'row',
},

  scroller: {
    marginHorizontal: 0,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  item: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    //marginRight: 5,
    margin: 2,
  },
  forcedPathImage: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 24,
    height: 36,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
});
```

In fact the problem is that, any changing in flex value doesn't work in `insideImageContainer` or `imageContianer`. Can you help me to fix this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting `marginRight: 'auto'` on the element that is to the left of your buttons.

Comment: @JonKoops: Thanks for your answer and sorry for my question that was long. Unfortunately, nothing happen and it keeps as before.

Comment: @JonKoops: Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Perhaps if you could provide a more succinct version of your component structure. It's hard to reproduce this since it has a lot unrelated logic. Maybe a simplified version in plain HTML and CSS to play around with?

Comment: @JonKoops: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, the components are so huge and complex. However, I try to see if I can do that.

Comment: Try removing `flex:1` from `buttomContainer`. Then `componentContainer` should grow to fill the space and `buttomContainer` should be pushed to the right. At the moment, they're each trying to fill half of the row.

Comment: @RobHogan: Thanks a lot for your answer, as I remove it, all the buttons become vertical.

Comment: @RobHogan: I should mention that, I also deleted 'flexDirection' there. However, in both cases by changing the flex in 'componentContainer' nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a minimum this should be all you need:

```
Toolbar = () => <View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.componentContainer}>
    <Text>Icon</Text>
    <Text>Title</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.buttomContainer}>
    <Text>Button1</Text>
    <Text>Button2</Text>
  </View>
</View> 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  componentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  buttomContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  }
});
```

[See this running in Expo](https://snack.expo.io/H1UwD-cCb)

The thing to think about when using flex layouts is; which component should take up the spare space? Give that component a `flex: 1` property. (And if multiple component should share the same space, split the flex between them).

In this case you don't want your `buttomContainer` (typo?) to be any bigger than it needs to be. You want the `componentContainer` to grow (flex) as big as it can and push the `buttomContainer` to the right.

Comment: It was a good answer, However my code secretly does't work like that. Thanks, I voted up. :)

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. If you can reproduce the problem you're having in expo I'd be happy to have another look.

Comment: That doesn't run (try "tap to play" in snack, or run it on your phone via the expo app) - you'll need to either add some of your other project files or cut out some of the stuff not relevant to the problem.

Comment: According to your templet code it finally works. Thanks a lot. :)